# Fetch array for dropdown list with MySQL data in a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, html-select

How can i start it? I know that i need to make an mysql query, but how to transform data, in options in the dropdown list. And remember, it's inside a form, to send the result from a MySQL table.

(EDIT)

I am working inside a printf That is what i want:

```
<?php ob_start();
include('/../../config.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['edit_id']) && !empty($_POST['edit_id'])) { 

$edit_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edit_id']); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, nome, cidade, pais, base, isactive,   admin, dov, checador, dinheiro, email, datanascimento, profissao, idivao, idvatsim, horas, rank FROM acars_users WHERE `id`='".$edit_id."'");
$resultdl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acars_hubs");

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl); 


printf("<div  align=\"center\">
<br><form method=\"post\" action=\"editar2.php\">
<p><font size=\"2\" face=\"Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\"   align=\"center\">Modifique os campos que deseja para <strong>editar este membro.</font><br>
<br>

<table width=\"700\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" >
<tr>
    <td>Base Operacional:</td>
    <td><label for=\"hub\"></label>
      <select name=\"hub\">
         <option>".$dl['name']."</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></br></br>
<input name=\"edit_id\" value=\"$edit_id\" type=\"hidden\">
<input type=\"image\" src=\"img/Editar.PNG\" width='85' height='30'></form>
</form>

</table> 
</div>

");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result));
while ($dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl));
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem. My first `$dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl, MYSQL_ASSOC);` pulls the first row from the table. When I start `while` loop the `mysql_fetch_array` picks up with the next row. So, the solution is remove the first call. This is the final code:

```
<?php 
   include('../../../../../config.php'); 

    if(isset($_POST['edit_id']) && !empty($_POST['edit_id'])) {

    $edit_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['edit_id']); 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acars_users WHERE `id`='".$edit_id."'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $resultdl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acars_hubs");

    printf("<div  align=\"center\">
    <form method=\"post\" action=\"actions/actions_editar.php\">
    ");

           while ($dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        printf(" 
        <option value=".$dl["id"].">".$dl["name"]."</option>;
        ");

           }

    printf("
        <input name=\"edit_id\" value=\"$edit_id\" type=\"hidden\">
        <input type=\"image\" src=\"../../images/botao_editar.PNG\" width='85' height='30'></form>
        ");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think this will help me. I think you should change the question, if you can, to reflect what the real problem is. I.e., "Fetch array results for a dropdown form list". I read this by chance out of curiosity, but may have found the answer to a problem I was having with a while loop.

Comment: Never mind; I edited the question. (PHPMyAdmin is not relevant to the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<select>
<?php while($row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")){ ?>
<option><?=$row['column']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I actually have 3, but only 2 results appear. The first one is always hidden. That is what i did: `code ....<td class=\"tabeladados\">Base Operacional:</td>
    <td class=\"tabeladados\"><label for=\"hub\"></label>
          <select name=\"hub\">
       ");
    
       while ($dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl)){
    
             echo "<option value=" . $dl['name'] . ">" . $dl['name'] . "</option>";
    
    }
    
    printf("
    
          </select>
    </td>....`

Comment: What does $resultd1 equal?

Comment: Its resultdL, not d1, its dL from DropList. `code $dl = mysql_fetch_array($resultdl);` and `code $resultdl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acars_hubs");`